# My code is not printing MIXED value while logic is ascii value of letters and numbers

Tags: python-3.x, string, ascii

Given a string, print whether it is a number, word, or mixed with digit and letters.
If all the characters are numeric values, print NUMBER. If they are all letters, print
WORD. If it is mixed, print MIXED.

```
value = 'nka121fsd132'
for i in range(len(value)):
    if ((ord(value[i])>=65 and ord(value[i])<=90) or
        (ord(value[i])>=97 and ord(value[i])<=122)):
        name="WORD"
    elif (ord(value[i])>=48 and ord(value[i])<=57):
        name="NUMBER"
    elif (((ord(value[i])>=65 and ord(value[i])<=90) or
          (ord(value[i])>=97 and ord(value[i])<=122)) or 
          (ord(value[i])>=48 and ord(value[i])<=57)):
        name="MIXED"
print(name)
```

It's printing `NUMBER` here, not `MIXED`.

Comment: Output is `NUMBER` because the last element of value is a number. Your loop iterates through all elements and `name` is set on each iteration. By the way - `for i in value:` is the pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_input = input('Enter your desired input:')
count_integer = 0
count_alphabet = 0
count_mixed = 0
for i in user_input: 
  ord_ver = ord(i)
  if (ord_ver>=65 and ord_ver<=90) or (ord_ver>=97 and ord_ver<=122) :
    count_alphabet += 1
  elif ord_ver>=48 and ord_ver<=57:
    count_integer += 1
if count_integer > 0 and count_alphabet > 0:
  print('MIXED')
elif count_integer > 0:
  print('NUMBER')
else:
  print('WORD')
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has built-in functions for these tasks, see String Methods at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

```
value = 'nka121fsd132'
print('False' if not value.isprintable()  # no printable characters
      else 'EMPTY' if value == ''         # empty string
      else 'NUMBER' if value.isdigit()    # only digits
      else 'WORD' if value.isalpha()      # only characters
      else 'MIXED'                        # digits, characters, spaces
      )
```

Output:

```
MIXED
```